# Is there product/application/service to sync from e.g. Live calendar to e.g. Google calendar

Tags: calendars

Currently when using multiple calendars (Outlook.com, Google, iCloud and so on) all those are individual. One can see the hub view for those on Windows Phone of course but how about adding something to Google and seeing it on Outlook.com calendar also? So full bi-directional(multi-directional) sync is what I'm after for I suppose.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean - all the connected calendars show on the built in calendar for me? If you actually mean duplicating events between the multiple calendars for viewing off the phone, that would be out of the scope of this site, but you might find answers on the [site for web applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You can search for a app in Market or go to google calendar and see if there is a import option.
Look: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-sync-windows-live-and-google-calendar/

> To view a calendar from Windows Live Calendar in Google Calendar, log into your Windows Live account and open the [Windows Live Calendar website](https://bay01.calendar.live.com/calendar/calendar.aspx). Click the *Share* button at the top of the page and select the calendar you want to sync.
>
> Enable the *Send people a view-only link to your calendar* check box on the sharing page. Click the ICS link under *Links that show event details*.
>
> [image]
>
> Select the link that appears and copy it to your clipboard (right-click the selected text and click copy.)
>
> Next, log into your Google account and open Google Calendar. Click the arrow to the right of Other calendars and select *Add by URL*.
>
> [image]
>
> Paste the URL you copied earlier into the URL box. However, change the *webcals://* at the beginning of the URL to *http://*. If you don’t make this change, Google Calendar will fail to understand the URL.
>
> Once you’ve done this, click *Add Calendar* and the calendar will appear in your Google Calendar account.
>
> [image]
>
> Google Calendar will automatically check the calendar for updates. Any changes you make in Windows Live Calendar will appear on your Google Calendar. To add other calendars from Windows Live Calendar, repeat this process.
>
> You can click the arrow to the right of the calendar in your calendar list to assign a color. Click the *Calendar Settings* link after clicking the arrow to assign a name to the calendar."

Source: [www.Makeuseof.com](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-sync-windows-live-and-google-calendar)

Comment: @Indrek Can you now delete your thumb down?

Comment: It should be noted that, at least on the Microsoft side, these instructions apply to the older Windows Live Calendar, rather than the current Outlook.com Calendar, though it's possible that the overall steps still work. Not sure how up-to-date the instructions are on the Google side.

Comment: SAME THING! I tested it!!!!!

Comment: No need to shout, it was just a caveat. If you tested the instructions, then that's great.

Comment: You DON'T have to -1 my answer just because you don't like it!

Comment: I actually downvoted your answer because in its initial form it was unhelpful. That's what downvotes are for, you shouldn't take it so personally. Also, that's why I also posted the comments - to help you improve it. I've removed my downvote now (had to edit your answer because otherwise votes are locked in after a certain amount of time).

Comment: What inteligence from you to -1 all my answers.....the world is as bad due to people like you!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14277/discussion-between-leonte-george-and-indrek)

Answer (score 1):

There might be an option to subscribe online calendars in  almost all web calendar applications.

May be these too might help you.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/38964

https://superuser.com/q/561660/193642